# MySQL loops in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, phpmyadmin

I've used the `SQL` command line in phpMyAdmin to update my database directly before (rather than writing a C script). I'm wondering if it's possible to do something a little more complicated.

I have two tables. `tableB` is currently empty, and exists because I want to change the structure of `tableA`. (I want to drop `snum` from `tableA`.)

```
tableA
-------
unum   (int)
snum   (int)
etc

tableB
-------
unum   (int)
snum   (int)
```

What I need to do is create one record in `tableB` for each and every record in `tableA`, copying across `unum` and `snum` as I go. Then I will remove `snum` from tableA and henceforth use a `LEFT JOIN` to combine the tables. (The problem is that there can be multiple `snum` values for each `unum` which wasn't originally foreseen.)

Is it possible to populate `tableB` just through a MySQL command in phpMyAdmin, or do I need to write a little script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop isn't necessary here, you can simply do this since you want to copy rows from `tableA` to `tableB`. execute `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO TableB (unum, snum)
SELECT unum, snum
FROM tableA
```

*follow-up question: what will be the value for `snum` since there are many of them on each `unum`? do you want to insert it all or selected only?*

Comment: Thanks for this. You're my new best friend - two answers in two days :) Regarding your follow-up question, there is only currently one snum for each unum at present. Once I've made the db change, I can add the extra data :)